# Como personalizar somente um tipo de post para aparecer no single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin de empregos para wordpress, peguei como base o wpjobmanager está saindo tudo bem, até eu me deparar com o seguinte, o plugin quando o usuário clica para ver mais sobre o determinado emprego abre o single.php porém ele modifica do jeito dele... Meio difícil explicar, O single php irá conter o loop do wordpress que mostrará o conteúdo daquele post, porém esse plugin consegue personalizar somente o post deles(de emprego). Pensei em alterar o single para se adequar ao plugin mas isso estaria errado pois teria que modificar o tema, e a ideia do plugin é pegar em qualquer tema.

Exemplo do que o plugin faz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a documentação [aqui](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), vc pode criar um novo single com o nome dentro do tema atual.

```
single-<post-type>.php
```

se for emprego o post type

```
single-emprego.php
```

Para uma alteração a partir do plugin, você pode usar

```
add_filter('template_include', 'meu_single_personalizado');
function meu_single_personalizado( $template ) {

    if (is_singular("emprego")) {
        $template = 'caminho/no/plugin/para/o/single.php';
    }

    return $template;
}
```

como pode ser visto nesta [resposta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55763/is-it-possible-to-define-a-template-for-a-custom-post-type-within-a-plugin-indep)

Comment: Opa obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente não serve, pois não posso alterar o tema, o plugin deve funcionar em todos

Comment: @AndersonHenrique eu entendi isso anderson, por isso dei duas sugestões para ficar registrado inclusive para os futuros usuários que procurarem. Para uso no plugin pode utilizar o filtro template_include, esse template fica dentro do seu plugin. =)

Comment: Opa Funcionou, muito obrigado